# How to convert a .TIF into a GeoTiFF

Tags: python, google-maps, bing-maps, geotiff

I am using a function to download Google map images given a pair of latitude and longitude of the area. I can manage to change the format of the downloading images into jpeg or png or tiff but I would like to save the images as Geotiff in order to keep the spatial information. Is there a way to do that? Like input the existing image and then input the format I want it to be converted. Here is the code

```
def __init__(self, lat, lng, zoom=12, layer='s'):

    self._lat = lat
    self._lng = lng
    self._zoom = zoom
    self._layer = layer

def getXY(self):


    tile_size = 256

    numTiles = 2 << self._zoom

    # Find the x_point given the longitude
    point_x = (tile_size / 2 + self._lng * tile_size / 360.0) * numTiles // tile_size

    # Convert the latitude to radians and take the sine
    sin_y = math.sin(self._lat * (math.pi / 180.0))

    # Calulate the y coorindate
    point_y = ((tile_size / 2) + 0.5 * math.log((1 + sin_y) / (1 - sin_y)) * -(
    tile_size / (2 * math.pi))) * numTiles // tile_size

    return int(point_x), int(point_y)

def generateTiles(self, **kwargs):


    start_x = kwargs.get('start_x', None)
    start_y = kwargs.get('start_y', None)
    tile_width = kwargs.get('tile_width', 5)
    tile_height = kwargs.get('tile_height', 5)

    # Check that we have x and y tile coordinates
    if start_x == None or start_y == None:
        start_x, start_y = self.getXY()

    # Determine the size of the image
    width, height = 256 * tile_width, 256 * tile_height

    # Create a new image of the size require
    map_img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))

    for x in range(0, tile_width):
        for y in range(0, tile_height):
            url = f'https://mt0.google.com/vt?lyrs={self._layer}&x=' + str(start_x + x) + '&y=' + str(start_y + y) + '&z=' + str(self._zoom)
            current_tile = str(x) + '-' + str(y)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, current_tile)

            im = Image.open(current_tile)
            map_img.paste(im, (x * 256, y * 256))

            os.remove(current_tile) 
            

            current_tile = str(x) + '-' + str(y)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, current_tile)

            im = Image.open(current_tile)
            map_img.paste(im, (x * 256, y * 256))

            os.remove(current_tile)

        return map_img

def main():
    gmd = ImagesDownloader(lat, lon, 15, layer ='s')

print("The tile coorindates are {}".format(gmd.getXY()))

try:
    # Get the high resolution image
    img = gmd.generateTiles()
except IOError:
    print("Could not generate the image - try adjusting the zoom level and checking your coordinates")
else:
    # Save the image to disk
    img.save("high_resolution_image.tif")
    print("The map has successfully been created")


if __name__ == '__main__':  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using GDAL to create the GeoTiff. There are Python binding available if that's what you're working in. https://gdal.org/api/python.html You may want to check the terms of use for your mapping service, exporting and saving images is often not permitted.